# How to find that "NT AUTHORITY" it is not an AD server?

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to read an msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor, to find whether it contains a Full Access to another person. The access control entries contain the trustees in the netbios format (`DOMAIN\Username`).

```
SecurityDescriptor secDesc = (SecurityDescriptor)userDirectoryEntry.Properties["msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor"].Value;
AccessControlList usrAcl = (AccessControlList)secDesc.DiscretionaryAcl;
foreach (AccessControlEntry ace in (IEnumerable)usrAcl)
{
    var netbiosDn = ace.Trustee.Split('\\')[0];
    var netbiosUser = ace.Trustee.Split('\\')[1];
    // now, the problem:
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
        new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, netbiosDn), 
        netbiosUser
    );
```

This works until the last line, where I have to connect to the correct AD server and get some user info. Obviously, this fails when there is no server available for that domain, like any of the "NT AUTHORITY" or "BUILTIN" "domains". It does not only fail, it needs quite some time until it does.

How on earth would I distinguish which ones are AD domains, where I can connect to the AD server, and which ones aren't?

Some example users I may find in the Security Descriptor, just for you to get a feel for the problem:

- CONTOSO\Alex
- CONTOSO\Michael
- SUBDOMAIN\Kirk
- TRUSTED\George
- NTPD\ChiefBrown
- NT AUTHORITY\SELF
- NT INSTANS\INTERAKTIV
- BUILTIN\Администраторы
- BUILDING2\Владимир
- VORDEFINERT\Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`SecurityIdentifier.IsWellKnown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.iswellknown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can pass various values, including [`WellKnownSidType.NTAuthoritySid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine what kind of SID you have.

(See also [this PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/a/503048/1440) code on translating into readable names.)

Comment: @Alexander It's all in that same namespace: `(new NTAccount(username)).Translate(typeof(SecuirtyIdentifier))`.